# Silverlight: Show the same controls on every page

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, user-interface

I'm building a SL4 app. I have two controls, a top search bar and a bottom favorites bar, that I'd like to be present on every page. I'm not sure what the best way to do this is.

My current approach uses a nav frame as the root visual:

**App.xaml.cs:**

`this.RootVisual = new NavFrame();`

**NevFrame.xaml**:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <my:TopSearchBar x:Name="topSearchBar" Grid.Row="0"/>

    <navigation:Frame x:Name="navigationFrame" Source="/HomePage.xaml" Grid.Row="1"/>

    <my:BottomFavoritesBar x:Name="bottomFavoritesBar" Grid.Row="2"/>

</Grid>
```

Then, I'd change pages within the Frame, leaving the persistent elements in place. Is this the correct approach, or is there some other preferred pattern?

However, if I do this, I'm not sure how to let the `TopSearchBar` and `BottomFavoritesBar` user controls do navigation. (In general, I'm not sure how to do navigation directly from a `UserControl`.)

When `TopSearchBar` was a member of each page, I'd have this code on each page's code-behind:

```
topSearchBar.ParentPage = this;
```

`TopSearchBar` could then use this reference to do navigation:

```
ParentPage.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/SearchPage.xaml?q=" + searchBox.Text, UriKind.Relative));
```

Is there a better way to do this? It feels somewhat awkward. If navigation requires a reference to a page, how can I pass that reference from `NavFrame`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The appropriate approach is to add a dependency property to both the `TopSearchBar` and `BottomFavoritesBar` called "Navigator" (or whatever you prefer) that has the type `INavigate`.

Your xaml would look like this:-

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White"> 
    <Grid.RowDefinitions> 
        <RowDefinition /> 
        <RowDefinition /> 
        <RowDefinition /> 
    </Grid.RowDefinitions> 

    <my:TopSearchBar x:Name="topSearchBar" Grid.Row="0" Navigator="{Binding ElementName=navigationFrame}"/> 

    <navigation:Frame x:Name="navigationFrame" Source="/HomePage.xaml" Grid.Row="1"/> 

    <my:BottomFavoritesBar x:Name="bottomFavoritesBar" Grid.Row="2" Navigator="{Binding ElementName=navigationFrame}" /> 

</Grid>
```

Now in your two Bar user controls navigation is simply:-

```
Navigator.Navigate(new Uri("/SearchPage.xaml?q=" + searchBox.Text, UriKind.Relative));
```

**Edit**

To create the dependency properties add this to your `TopSearchBar` class:-

```
    public INavigate Navigator
    {
        get { return GetValue(NavigatorProperty) as INavigate; }
        set { SetValue(NavigatorProperty, value); }
    }


    public static readonly DependencyProperty NavigatorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Navigator",
            typeof(INavigate),
            typeof(TopSearchBar),
            new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

Duplicate this in your `BottomFavoritesBar` class but change the reference to `TopSearchBar`.

Comment: Can you show how you would use Dependency Properties to do this? I'm not sure exactly what they are, or why you need them here.

Comment: nice! that works great. Can you explain why I need a Dependency Property here, and not just a normal CLR property?

Comment: @Rosarch:  Binding requires the target to be a dependency property

Answer (score 1):

I suggest looking in to Prism CAL Pattern

This way you can create regions for your containers and the region(s) you want changed from page to page... it's simple, you just swap the new one to replace the old one while the others remain in place. It's a much more streamlined approach in my opinion.

http://development-guides.silverbaylabs.org/Video/Silverlight-Prism

Comment: Especially look for a View injection on Region object or create composite view... PRISM4 manual has good explanation how to do it.